when using transformer, why image embedding is a list of float, but text embedding is a list of list of float
In order to get image embedding:
    batch_size = 1
    inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
    image_features = model.get_image_features(inputs.pixel_values)[batch_size-1]
    embeddings = image_features.numpy().astype(np.float32)

here embeddings is a list of float.
In order to get text embedding:
    inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors = "pt")
    text_embeddings = model.get_text_features(**inputs)
    embedding_as_np = text_embeddings.cpu().detach().numpy()
    embeddings = embedding_as_np.astype(np.float32)

here embeddings is a list of list of float, with only one item.
Why text embedding and image embedding returned differently. why text embedding returns a list of list?

Which model are you using?

@cronoik openai/clip-vit-base-patch16
